# Extract ZipArchive entry to blob storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Using the normal Windows file system, the `ExtractToFile` method would be sufficient:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(uploadedFile.InputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read, true))
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries.Where(x => x.Length > 0))
    {
        entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(location, entry.Name));
    }
}
```

Now that we are using Azure, this obviously needs to change as we are using blob storage.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ZipArchiveEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.aspx) class has an [`Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open.aspx) method which returns a stream. What you could do is create a blob using that stream.

```
static void ZipArchiveTest()
        {
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
            CloudBlobContainer container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("temp");
            container.CreateIfNotExists();
            var zipFile = @"D:\node\test2.zip";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(zipFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(fs))
                {
                    var entries = archive.Entries;
                    foreach (var entry in entries)
                    {
                        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(entry.FullName);
                        using (var stream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had written a blog post on the same topic with details here [Extract a zip file stored as Azure Blob with this simple method](http://msdevzone.net/2017/07/07/extract-a-zip-file-stored-in-azure-blob/)

Just in case if your zip file also stored as a blob in storage, the below snippet from my above mentioned blog post helps.

```
// Save blob(zip file) contents to a Memory Stream.
 using (var zipBlobFileStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(zipBlobFileStream);
    await zipBlobFileStream.FlushAsync();
    zipBlobFileStream.Position = 0;
    //use ZipArchive from System.IO.Compression to extract all the files from zip file
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(zipBlobFileStream))
        {
           //Each entry here represents an individual file or a folder
           foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
           {
              //creating an empty file (blobkBlob) for the actual file with the same name of file
              var blob = extractcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference(entry.FullName);
              using (var stream = entry.Open())
              {
                 //check for file or folder and update the above blob reference with actual content from stream
                 if (entry.Length > 0)
                    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
              }

             // TO-DO : Process the file (Blob)
             //process the file here (blob) or you can write another process later 
             //to reference each of these files(blobs) on all files got extracted to other container.
           }
        }
     }
```